# How to determine that an application in being used by the user (in android)?

Tags: java, android, profile

I want to record what application is being used by the user at every time. I can write a program to save the processes running on the phone, but I want to know which one is the one that the user is interacting with.

Comment: You can't really.  There is/was an api call, but it was highly unreliable and marginally useless - even when it was accurate, it might report an IME that user was typing _with_, rather than the application the user was typing input _for_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what Chris was referring to in the comment, and I don't know how reliable it is, but you can iterate through the list returned by [ActivityManager#getRunningAppProcesses ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29) :

> ```
> public List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> getRunningAppProcesses ()
> ```
>
> Since: API Level 3
>
> Returns a list of application processes that are running on the device.
>
> Returns a list of `RunningAppProcessInfo` records, or null if there are no running processes (it will not return an empty list). This list ordering is not specified.

Then, check for the importance field of each `ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo`:

> ```
> public int importance
> ```
>
> Since: API Level 3
>
> The relative importance level that the system places on this process. May be one of `IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND`, `IMPORTANCE_VISIBLE`, `IMPORTANCE_SERVICE`, `IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND`, or `IMPORTANCE_EMPTY`. These constants are numbered so that "more important" values are always smaller than "less important" values.

You may have a service polling every 30 seconds or so and log those values.

(BTW, you want to look for those `IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND` and `IMPORTANCE_VISIBLE`)